# OBSOLETE - ChatSEy - An Android App for SE Chat

Tags: app, obsolete, chat, android

> ## App removed
>
> Now that we have a [mobile chat that doesn't suck](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273727/test-the-new-mobile-chat/273733#273733), I've taken this down.

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

- Completely overhauled styles, including default and dark themes
- Reply to, star and flag messages
- Slide-out Sidebar for easy menu/star list access
- Tweaks to make typing easier (including Return -> Send, @username completion)

The app works by injecting extra CSS and JS into the standard Stack Exchange chat window. It comprises only of client-side code. No data is sent to any servers other than those belonging to Stack Exchange.

### Download

- <del>Get it on the [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tommedley.chatsey)</del> (Dead Link.)
- <del>Get the [apk download](http://chatsey.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/remote/builds/ChatSEy.apk)</del> (Dead Link.)
- Get the [source](https://github.com/fredley/chatsey)

### Changelog

- **v1.1** - Log in should now work on older (<4.4) versions of Android. You need to log into an SE site, then go back to chat. This process has been semi-automated.

### Bugs

[Report them on github](https://github.com/fredley/chatsey/issues), and for bonus points submit a pull request!

*This app is brought to you by [@fredley](https://stackapps.com/users/4644/fredley) & [@RedRiderX](https://stackapps.com/users/25076/redriderx)*

[image]

Comment: I really can't upvote this until it supports chat.meta.SE.

Comment: @michaelb958 Noted, I'll get a fix out. Are any other domains missing?

Comment: There's only chat.SE (supported), chat.meta.SE (as above), and chat.SO (might want to add that).

Comment: @michaelb958 I had chat.SO but not chat.meta.SE. I should have an updated apk today.

Comment: @michaelb958 Fixed. It may take a little while for the Play store to push you the new binary.

Comment: Fastest bug turnaround time *ever*.

Comment: @michaelb958 6-8 *seconds!*

Comment: It doesn't work for me. "Your browser does not support StackExchange global authentication. Please enable cookies, and make sure you have a reasonably modern browser. See help for details, or log in via StackExchange.com." So what's the purpose of the app then?

Comment: But I can join Root Access" from all rooms list and it says "logged in" at the bottom. I can only view the chat conversations, I cannot type anything. And if I click on "logged in" it takes me to the same message as I already posted. *This is on a Galaxy S4 Plus, if that helps.*

Comment: @sammyg what version of Android are you running?

Comment: Android 4.3, kernel 3.4.0-2210443. Model number GT-I9506.

Comment: @sammyg I'll try and see what's going wrong with an emulator

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14141/discussion-between-sammyg-and-fredley)

Comment: It would be cool if there was a moderator option that kept the edit and remove links available when selecting any message.

Comment: @AJHenderson If I can reliably detect if you're a moderator, then sure, I'll look into it!

Comment: @AJHenderson I've had a look, and from the mobile chat interface it's basically impossible to tell if you're a moderator.

Comment: @fredley - that's unfortunate.  I don't know much about JavaScript, but can you tell anything from the color used for your name in your own messages?  I noticed that the mobile chat client does make your messages a different color and if the name is in blue for your own messages, then you are a mod.

Comment: Oh, just did some quick checking as far as what is available in the markup for a moderator.  On the chat.sidebar.loadUser calls, there is "is_moderator: true" in the user list.  Not sure if that might help too.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone interested in running this apps mobile chat interface on your desktop (as in a sidebar chat window with reply support!) the author has responded in record time to [my request](https://github.com/fredley/chatsey/issues/4) and [provided a userscript version](https://gist.github.com/fredley/e4a51ac50b98e8f580d4)!